# how to get control inside splitcontainer?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My code is

```
((DataGridView)(Application.OpenForms["frmMasterInterface"]
.Controls["splitContainer1"]
.Controls["splitContainer1.Panel1"]
.Controls["pnlLeft"]
.Controls["grbfittingTypes"]
.Controls["dgvitems"])).Rows[RowIndex].Cells["sizeRange"].Value
```

I want to get value of row of datagridview from another form.
Please help.

Thanks & Regards,

-Nitin

Comment: Actually the datagridview is inside splitcontainer's panel1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably hundreds of ways to do this, I've just tried the following, first getting a reference to the split container and then accessing `Panel1` directly, and it works:

```
SplitContainer sc = (SplitContainer)Application.OpenForms[0].Controls["splitContainer1"];
DataGridView dg = (DataGridView)sc.Panel1.Controls["dataGridView1"];
```

That said, if I was you I'd look at instead creating a property on your `frmMasterInterface` to access the `DataGridView` directly, and then passing a reference to `frmMasterInterface` to the second form.

Answer (score 0):

i Hope that you wanna get the data by click the cell content.from a differnt.It works for me as u defined ,hope it helps to you.

```
DataGridView dggg; //Globally Declared
private void dd()
{
    var form = (frmMasterInterface)Application.OpenForms["frmMasterInterface"];//Form Name
    if (form == null) return;
    foreach (DataGridView dgv in form.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        if (dgv.Name == "dataGridView1") //name of data grid view
        {
            dggg = dgv;
            dgv.CellMouseClick += Datagirdmouseclick;
        }
}

private void Datagirdmouseclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

    Trace.WriteLine(dggg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["sizeRange"].Value);
}
```

Hope it helps.